# How do you get the old task view back?

Tags: windows-10, task-view

When Microsoft introduced timeline in Windows 10 version 1803 they rewrote task view. It was a very sloppy job and they evidently haven't ever opened it themselves. I could go on and on about it. Disabling timeline doesn't bring back the old task view.

I am aware that you can disable the new keyboard (introduced in v1709) to get the old one by creating a DWORD called "DisableNewKeyboardExperience" set to 1 in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7 in registry editor. Is there a similar such registry tweak to bring back the old timeline?

I'm currently on version 1909.

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot of the "old" and "new" views? I don't have access to an old machine now, but alt-tab brings up a brief take manager while win-tab brings up the new task view. I'm guessing that the old task manager is not what you mean. I kindof like the new view as I can easily see what documents I opened and when, allowing me to pick up things where I left off. Granted I only use that at work and haven't touched it at home, but it does have a place...

Comment: the old task view had virtual desktops at the bottom. They look very similar otherwise (apart from timeline which is enabled by default)
new task view: https://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/xlarge/public/field/image/2018/07/task-view-windows-10-.jpg?itok=0WwayAfq
old task view: https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2015/07/windows10taskview-100598445-large.jpg

I personally don't really need timeline but that's not my issue with the new task view. It's the performance and the messed up "animations".

Comment: Virtual desktops are now at the top? Is that the only real change?

Comment: sorry I accidentally submitted my comment when I pressed enter, thinking it would add a new line.

Comment: @Mokubai it's been a while since I've seen the old task view. the old one positions windows differently too

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 1909 and still have the "old" task taskview. I don't have under the specified registry key a `DisableNewKeyboardExperience` item.

Comment: @harrymc that registry key is for the touch keyboard. 
It's really interesting that you still have the old task view. I'm not sure if we both understand each other correctly. A screenshot would clarify things :)

Comment: @koala you can [edit] your question to add screenshot, though initially you may only be able to post links which other people can convert to images. I would recommend posting the images to http://imgur.com so that people can migrate it to the image host Stack uses. You may also want to register your account here so you don't lose the ability to edit or comment on this question if your browser (or other software) clears your site cookies.

Comment: Your images are a bit too small. Here's mine : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zielc.jpg

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the screenshot. You have the new task view. My apologies for the order of the screenshots in my other comment. I posted the new task view before the old one. The images I linked to in my comment were just from Google Images. It's peculiar how large the windows are in your task view. Even on screens with a similar aspect ratio I still see smaller windows.

Edit: here's a better screenshot of the old task view: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BatWbZ_s8P4/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative answer : Not possible.

The Task View feature is built into Explorer, and at the moment there is
no known registry setting that can control it.

To show that it's built-into Explorer, execute the following command to
invoke it:

```
explorer shell:::{3080F90E-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}
```

I went as far as tracing the execution of showing the Task View, and found that
Windows doesn't even load a DLL to execute it.

I also searched the registry for anything that contains the string "taskview",
and only found the well-known registry key
`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
with its item of `ShowTaskViewButton`.

Your only solution is to stay forever on an older version of Windows 10,
which is of course absolutely not a good idea, or wait for this function to be
externalized by Microsoft (which could perhaps never happen).

Comment: Thanks Harry. Aw :( task view has something to do with UWP and UWP stuff is often hard to deal with. I don't think it's possible to get Windows Ink Workspace's Sketchpad back either because it's also UWP.